# what is the fastest and cost efficient way of moving objects from one s3 folder to another folder in same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, aws-cli

I have an **example** bucket with demo folder containing sub-folders and files in it. 
BucketStructure:

```
example/demo/*.jpeg #.jpeg files 
example/demo/sub-folder1
example/demo/sub-folder2
```

My objective is to move all the `.jpeg` files from `demo/` folder excluding `.jpeg` files from `sub-folder1` & `sub-folder2` to a new folder `/example/archive-jpeg/`.

Seeking help to get fastest and cost efficient way using aws-cli: using awscli v2

1. list all `.jpeg` objects in immediate `/demo` folder and
2. moving them to `/archive-jpeg` folder
3. deleting the `.jpeg` from `/demo` folder after archival

Thank You!

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using lambda expressions which is the most efficient way to do or you can create one utility and read from the location and again write to another folder , but i would recommend over this to lambda expressions.

Comment: aws-cli help what I'm looking for, writing lambda will again take time @CharanjeetSingh

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket/demo/  s3://bucket/target-folder/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpeg" --exclude "*/*"
```

The logic is:

- `aws s3 mv --recursive` tells it to move *all* objects
- `--exclude "*"` tells it to exclude all objects from being moved
- `--include "*.jpeg"` tells it to include objects ending with `.jpeg`
- `--exclude "*/*"` tells it to exclude anything in sub-directories (eg `sub-folder1/` and `sub-folder2/`)

See: [AWS CLI: Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

As for **fastest** and **cost efficient**, since you have specified that you want to do it via the AWS CLI, then there are no other options.

If you are willing to do it *without* the AWS CLI, then a faster way to move the objects would be to write some code that runs in parallel to send individual Copy and Delete API calls to Amazon S3. (There is no 'move' command in S3 — the AWS CLI is actually copying the objects and then deleting the original objects.)

Or, rather than moving objects as a batch, you could configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function that moves the files *as soon as they are created*, which would result in them moving 'faster' than running as a batch.

As for **cost efficient**, the objects need to be copied and deleted, which would result in API calls to Amazon S3 at a cost of `$0.005 per 1000 requests`. I don't think you could avoid these API calls, so there would be no way to make it even lower cost.

Comment: Thank you John, I found suggestion working for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I would appreciate you could share how to list specific .jpeg objects from /demo folder excluding subfolder .jpeg objects.

Comment: That one is getting a bit tricky. I could only do it by knowing the name of the subfolders: `aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix demo/ --query 'Contents[?ends_with(Key, \`.jpeg\`) == \`true\`]|[?starts_with(Key,\`demo/sub-folder1/\`)==\`false\`]|[?starts_with(Key,\`demo/sub-folder2/\`)==\`false\`].[Key]' --output text`

Comment: is there any byte limitation on moving objects with mv, as only 0 byte objects moved and for rest it considering all subfolders.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Feel free to create a new question and add full details.